# What is the syntax for the 'Query string value' in a view argument input?

Tags: views

down vote favorite
share [g+] share [fb] share [tw]

In Views (3.3) you have the possibility to provide an argument input once you set up a relationship and a contextual filter. One option is to get this argument from the Query string value.

I tried it with visiting a link like this:

```
....url_to_view_page?argument=foo
```

and also

```
....url_to_view_page?foo
```

and even

```
....url_to_view_page?q=foo
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What is the correct syntax for this in the URL?

Comment: I have never heard about this before. I can't find any choice for query string in the arguments section.

Comment: It really exists; if you select 'From context' (at the argument input window) and look under 'Token replacements' you should see 'Current page: Query string value'.

Comment: I've got Views 3.3 and am not seeing this option - screenshot might help here?

Answer (score 1):

Syntax depends on your view display path, e.g. for *page displays*.

For example, if your page display path is `url_to_view_page/%` then the syntax is:

`url_to_view_page/foo`.

If you do not have a path, then you'll always fall back on the *contextual filter not provided* behavior, this is always the case for blocks.

Answer (score 1):

when `Clean Url` is enable all Urls converted to `foo/bar/...` structure,The views contextual filter address is  `pageurl\arg1\arg2\....` So if you view page url is `url_to_view_page\%` then the Url can be like `url_to_view_page\foot`.

( also you can use `?q=url_to_view_page/foo`)